# Deleting the last record instead of selected one and how can I add edit function to it

Tags: php, mysqli, edit, sql-delete

I'm fetching data from database table into page when I'm trying to delete a particular record instead its deleting the last record in table.

This is `fetchtable.php`. How can i add edit functionality in it? Please if possible give a detailed answer:

```
<?php
require 'conn.php';
$tfetch = "select ID,firstname,lastname,gender,email, password from signup";
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare ($conn,$tfetch))
{
    mysqli_stmt_execute ($stmt); 
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result ($stmt, $id, $fn, $ln, $gen, $email, $pass );
    mysqli_stmt_store_result ($stmt);

}
mysqli_close ($conn);
?>
```

And this is the page in which I'm fetching:

```
<?php
include'fetchtable.php';
if(isset($_POST['del']))
{
    require 'conn.php';
    $id=$_POST['del_id'];
    $stmt = "DELETE FROM signup WHERE ID =$id";
    mysqli_query($conn,$stmt);
    mysqli_execute($stmt);
    $row=mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
    if($row==1)
    {
        echo " sucess ! record was deleted ";
    }
    else
    {
        echo " record was not deleted ";
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
    <?php
    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='2'";
    echo "<tr><td>ID</td><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>Gender</td><td>Email</td><td>Password</td><td>Delete</td>";
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
    {
        echo"<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$id."</td>";
        echo "<td>". "$fn" ."</td>";
        echo "<td>". "$ln" ."</td>";
        echo "<td>". "$gen"."</td>";
        echo "<td>". "$email"."</td>";
        echo "<td>". "$pass" ."</td>";
        echo '<td> <input type="hidden" name="del_id" value="'.$id.'" /> <input type="submit" name="del" value="delete" /> </td>';
        echo"</tr>";
    }
    ?>
</form>
```

EDIT : Found solution just include the while loop in form rather than including while within a form

Answer (score 0):

It's deleting the last record b/c you variable `$id` is same in both fetch and delete.

```
$delete_id = $_POST['del_id'];
$del_stmt = "DELETE FROM signup WHERE ID =$delete_id";
mysqli_query($conn,$del_stmt);
mysqli_execute($del_stmt);
```

Comment: How can i change this ?

Comment: m not sure how to do that (m new here )

Comment: I just replaced the $id with $delete_id in delete part.

Comment: still the same last record deleted plus m getiing two warnings 'Warning: mysqli_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, string given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/Userinfo.php on line 19' and 'Warning: mysqli_stmt_fetch() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, string given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/Userinfo.php on line 38'

Comment: I have updated the code. Can you show the table output?

Comment: still no change sir. last record is deleted

Comment: put include'fetchtable.php'; after delete condition.

Comment: still the last comment is deleted

Comment: I am not sure why the id is same. You have to debug few things. You should `echo $_POST['del_id']` this to check what id is being post.